# DC/OS (mesos/marathon) how set time to start killed instance of aplication

Tags: mesos, marathon, dcos

I have install DC/OS (3master and 7slave server - all Centos7)

I saw problem - when one of slave server shut down - mesos/marathon start killed instance of application after 5 minutes.

For example - I run in mesos/marathon 8 instance simple web application. When I shut down or deactivate network interface of one slave server marathon show that some instancje are killed. **From this moment mesos/marathon wait 5 minutes and start killed instance to another online slave server.**

My question is - how can I change this time? 5 minutes is to long. I read documentation of DC/OS but I can't find variable responsible for this.

I will be very thankful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a at the [Marathon command-line flags](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/command-line-flags.html). Based on your description, I guess the default for either `task_launch_timeout` or `scale_apps_interval` could be responsible for this.

I'm unsure though if this can be configured on the fly, or during installation in DC/OS. I saw that there's a quite recent enhancement request to [Make Marathon flags passable via environment variables](https://dcosjira.atlassian.net/browse/DCOS-253).